# How can I get stack trace of an exception along with the default error message in microsoft botframework sdk V4 using c#

Tags: c#, exception, botframework

I have created a bot in microsoft botframework sdk v4 using c# and it is working well but when I got any error it simply showing "sorry, it looks like something went wrong". I want to get stack trace of the exception along with that default message. How can I get that.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why you want to show the whole stack trace as a response of your bot to a normal user, but in case this is for testing only you can simply modify the `OnTurnError` handler. 
This could usually be found in your `Startup.cs` class.

```
// Catches any errors that occur during a conversation turn and logs them.
options.OnTurnError = async (context, exception) =>
{
    logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception}");
    await context.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.");
};
```

From there you can use `exception.StackTrace` in your message.

If you are aiming to have this in production then **don't do it**. Instead go for a TelemetryClient like [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#api-summary) and track exceptions there. This way you can post a nice and user friendly error message (if there is such) while still having some log information's in the backend to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It is working now, I am using it for only testing purpose not in production.